# Hiding some database columns in view file cakephp

Tags: view, cakephp-3.0

My cakephp application is working fine only that I don't want some columns from the database to be visible in the view.ctp file. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you post the code for `view.ctp` and the controller action?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just edit the view and remove the lines that output those columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the model layer by using the `$_hidden` array:

`protected $_hidden = ['your', 'columns', 'here'];`

You can read a bit more about it in the Cake docs [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#hiding-properties)